# Datepicker in Laravel 5.5 using Jquery-ui or Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-ui, laravel-5.5

I am trying to learn `Laravel 5.5` and I am again stuck when I was trying to add a **jquery datepicker** in my modal window (bootstrap). Due to some unknown reason there is always an error which says:-

> $("#last_renewal").datepicker() is not a function

I have properly added all the required files in the header section in the following manner:-

```
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
```

Now I am really confused what is the mistake i am doing. Except the datepicker everything in jquery works fine.

Please Suggest

Comment: Add js code for more details are you writing code inside $(document).ready() ?

Comment: @Jigs1212 Not working. The most i got is... there is some problem in my <head> area links. Because if I remove those links then it works fine. but still cant get whats making the error

Comment: which links 
can u update the question with the current head ?

Comment: Can you post the HTML too? Why is this tagged [bootstrap-4] when you seem to be using Bootstrap 3?

Comment: i create [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/sohokepusu/1/edit?html,output) and your code still works

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need to change your code like @BugFixer is suggesting, but I think you just need to change the order of your script tags. When I put `$("#last_renewal").datepicker()` before jQuery ui, i see the error you're seeing. Then, when I move it after jquery ui script tag and after the div it works. See my answer below.

By the way, I would have create a fiddle but I had some difficulty getting the order the way I wanted it.:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="last_renewal">
    </div>
<script>
$("#last_renewal").datepicker()  
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Everyone,

I found a way around. It seems that in HTML there is a option where `<input type="date" >` gives the same output as jquery or any other datepicker. I am still keeping the bounty open and hope this way around method is useful for others. It may be relevant to mention here that it may not work with old browsers.

Comment: What browser(s) and versions are you trying to get this working with?

Answer (score 0):

Use  this :

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="//use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
<script> 
    $('body').on('focus',"#last_renewal", function(){        
        $(this).datepicker();
    });

</script>
```

Comment: If this setting is used the default dropdown doesnt work on the menu

Comment: you need to add `<script>` part in footer.

Comment: where you have written this `$("#last_renewal").datepicker()` ? where is your datepicker initialization part

Comment: I used it in the footer. But seems the problem persists

Comment: did u check it in incognito mode of browser

Answer (score 0):

You have to initilize the element with `jQuery` in the `onReady` event

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>

<script>
$(function(){
    $("#last_renewal").datepicker()
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="last_renewal"></p>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a link to datepicker plugin. Put this after fontawesome reference.
for css use this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.css"/>
```

for java script plugin

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
```